# Does small circuits for a NP-complete problem contradict ETH?

Tags: circuit-complexity, sat, complexity, fine-grained

The remarks of the Theorem 4 in the paper "[On the complexity of circuit satisfiability](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1810000/1806724/p241-paturi.pdf?ip=141.20.24.31&id=1806724&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=2BA2C432AB83DA15%2E04C410D892D772C0%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&__acm__=1565347231_4832b735fa536dff74517e0cd84a3665)" claims that: if circuit satisfiability (CktSat) problem can be decided by deterministic circuits of $2^{o(n)}$ size, then ETH fails. However, there are no references and proofs for this statement in the paper, and it is hard for me to get proof of this statement.

In fact, I have tried to prove the following weaker statement but failed. "If $SAT \in P/poly$, then ETH fails."

**QUESTION:** How to prove that: if Circuit Satisfiability (CktSat) problem can be decided by deterministic circuits of $2^{o(n)}$ size, then ETH fails?

Comment: Its likely that what is being referred to in the paper is the nonuniform version of ETH. I have seen this mentioned elsewhere on this site. For example, see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42752/is-there-a-relation-between-bbh-black-box-hypothesis-and-seth-strong-exponent